# Multichain and Openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge

I'm currently experimenting with [multichain](http://multichain.com) and was wondering if open shift would be able to host the software. For it to work I'll need to run shell commands and network multiple instances.

Can open shift accommodate this?